# Thales Application

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I'm struggling with this exercice:
[image]

Let $ABCD$ be a trapezium. $AB$ and $CD$ intersect at $O$.

$OE \parallel BD$, $OF \parallel AC $ and $F,C,B,E$ are aligned points

- Prove that $EB=CF$

I think it's an application of Thales' theorem. I applied the theorem to the $\triangle$ s $OBF,OCE,OBC$ , but I don't see how to use it to prove that $EB=CF$.

I also noticed that we can prove that the triangles $OBE$ and $OCF$ are equal,  $OE=OF$ , $OB=OC$,  but I still need an equal angle in both triangles.
Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE! Please use [*MathJax*](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and provide an image (I would recommend you GeoGebra). This might help other users when it comes to answering the question. In my case, for instance, I find it difficult to understand what the exercise is about and what conditions are given... An image, as said, might also be very helpful ;)

Comment: @mathva I just did, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right ! The problem does indeed involve Thales' theorem , and similarity:-

[image]

Note that we have:-

$\triangle OEC \sim  \triangle DBC  \implies \frac{EC}{BC}=\frac{OC}{DC} \tag{1}$ 
$\triangle OFB \sim \triangle ACB \implies \frac{BF}{BC}=\frac{OB}{AB} \tag{2}$

But by [Thales' Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem)
 , the **RHS** of $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equal !

Therefore , $EC$ equals $BF$ , which implies $EB$ equals $CF$

Comment: It's clear now thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just Thales 3 times, in angles $\angle ECO, \angle BOC$ and $\angle FBO$:

$$\color{red}{EB\over BC} = {OD\over DC} = {OA\over AB} = \color{red}{CF\over BC}\implies EB = CF$$

Comment: I've never seen this kind of thalès! but thanks for answering